Good orbifold and Ricci flow with Dirichlet boundary conditions on $\Sigma$
An orbifold $\mathcal O$ is a metrizable topological space equipped with an atlas modeled on $\Bbb R^n/\Gamma,  \Gamma<O(n)$ finite. Let $\Sigma$ be the singular locus i.e. points modeled on $\mathrm{Fix}(\Gamma)/\Gamma$. Take $\Gamma_x$ to be the isotropy group of a point $x\in \mathcal O$. Assume $\dim \mathcal O=2$ and that $\mathcal O$ is good. This implies a constant curvature metric on $\mathcal O$. Geometrically there is a unique orbifold (which I will call the "interface orbifold") satisfying these conditions with maximal volume $\approx 1/2$ and positive constant Gaussian curvature $\approx 2$ which can be embedded in $[0,1]^3.$ We can take $\Sigma=\lbrace q_1,q_2  \rbrace$ where these points are the cone points i.e. $q_1=(0,0,0)$ and $q_2=(1,1,1)$.
It is known that the normalized Ricci flow converges to a constant curvature metric (this is due to only considering good orbifolds here. For bad orbifolds one can get "gradient solitons"). In the case I am presenting it would be desirable to have Dirichlet type boundary conditions on $\Sigma$, calculate the metric on $\mathcal I$ and shrink the surface (hence shrink it's volume) using some modified Ricci flow (with the Dirichlet conditions on the singluar locus) while preserving the constant curvature of the metric. This seems very possible however I would like to hear how this might be defined in the literature or given a sketch here. It could be more natural to use mean curvature flow and leverage the convexity of $\mathcal I$ which I suspect should remain convex for all time even when pushing the volume past the interface orbifold (where we'd obtain an increase in volume, retain convexity, but lose the metric of constant curvature).

Is there an existing definition in the literature of a normalized geometric flow that uses Dirichlet boundary conditions on the the singular locus of a good orbifold with a positive constant curvature metric?

